# How do I set the world spawn in minecraft? 1.12.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a adventure map, but the spawn is incorrect. I watched loads of videos, but cannot find something that works. Please help!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

use `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>`

Comment: No Problem. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands is a useful reference